# Play WS, how to transmit non English symbols?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I do some requests with scala and play ws.
One of the requests has non English characters (Russian in my case)

Query looks like this:

```
val data = "query=" + "Россия, Москва, шоссе Энтузиастов, 21с1" + "&sr=" + Json.obj("wkid" -> 4326)
val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = WS.url("http://someservise.com/").post(data)
```

They query doesn't work, but looks like it must.
In this case, I sniff packages with wireshark. And they show me this request like this:

```
query=, ,  , 211&sr={"wkid":4326}
```

and in hex:

```
0000   71 75 65 72 79 3d d0 a0 d0 be d1 81 d1 81 d0 b8  query=..........
0010   d1 8f 2c 20 d0 9c d0 be d1 81 d0 ba d0 b2 d0 b0  .., ............
0020   2c 20 d1 88 d0 be d1 81 d1 81 d0 b5 20 d0 ad d0  , .......... ...
0030   bd d1 82 d1 83 d0 b7 d0 b8 d0 b0 d1 81 d1 82 d0  ................
0040   be d0 b2 2c 20 32 31 d1 81 31 26 73 72 3d 7b 22  ..., 21..1&sr={"
0050   77 6b 69 64 22 3a 34 33 32 36 7d                 wkid":4326}
```

What I need to do, to transmit this query right?

Comment: urlencode the characters? `я` -> `%D0%9B`?

Comment: @mark-b That isn't right. The service, what receive this queries (as I see in documentation), need to get not encoded characters. Also I try that too, and it isn't work.

Comment: The non-English characters have to be encoded somehow as they're not represented in ASCII. To me, the wireshark looks like it may be correct  - for instance your "о" appears correctly as the UTF-8 encoding of D0 BE, and the "и" as D0 B8. So the query is being transmitted right, but decoded wrong by the recipient?